# Как загрузить все элементы div'а?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Я Пишу небольшое расширение для хрома, работающее с сайтом https://cs.money/ru/ Мне необходимо загрузить все элементы инвентаря пользователя, scroll методы не помогли. Подскажите как это правильно реализовать. Ниже то что я пробовал(каждый способ пронумерован):

```
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('items')[1];
      //1
      elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;  
      //2
      elem.scrollTo(0, 500);
      //3
      elem.scrollTo({
      top: 500,
      left: 0,});
```

Comment: Так вы распишите\покажите, как добавляются элементы инвенторя.

Comment: Элементы инвентаря подгружаются динамически, когда пользователь прокручивает скроллбар, каждый элемент представляет собой отдельный div. Во время прокрутки происходят запросы, разобраться с которыми я не смог, так как они пустые

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке